# Is it possible to run tensorflow-data-validation on MacOS with M1 chip?

Tags: tensorflow-data-validation

**Question:** Is it possible to run tensorflow-data-validation on MacOS with M1 chip?

**Steps taken:** I have created a conda environment (`tfdv38`) in which I have installed the [Mac-optimized TensorFlow](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos).

I have tried to install the package within the environment, this didn't work:

```
(tfdv38) ... % pip install tensorflow-data-validation
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-data-validation
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-data-validation
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's an open issue in TFDV repo which is about missing support for M1 mac, You can follow up with that issue for TFDV support on M1 mac. Thanks!

Comment: You can find the referenece issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/issues/205)

Comment: Seems their latest on the following forum is that it's weeks away not months. Being hopeful here haha https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/i-want-to-use-the-tfx-1-6-1-on-mac-m1-max/8110

Answer (score 3):

At the moment unfortunately we don't support TFT, TFX and TFDV for M1 Mac, We are currently working on this issue, and will have an update in the fairly near future. In the meantime, some users have reported success with Rosetta. Other options include using a VM. We understand that neither of those is ideal.

You can also check on our Tensorflow Forum, same discussion is going on [here](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/i-want-to-use-the-tfx-1-6-1-on-mac-m1-max/8110).

TFDV is tested on the following 64-bit operating systems. Supported platforms :

- macOS 10.14.6 (Mojave) or later
- Ubuntu 16.04 or later
- Windows 7 or later